# Azure Create ARM Template To Create Vm In An Existing Vnet and Subnet

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

I want to deploy VM in the existing vnet and subnet. Instead of entering vnet and subnet name, can I get the list of vnet available in a Resource Group and make it as a user-selectable, same for subnet.

Answer (score 0):

no, this is not possible, you need to do this with powershell, for example, and then pass that as an input to the ARM template. it would something like this:

```
$vnets = Get-AzVirtualNetwork
$vnet = $vnets | Out-GridView -PassThru
$subnet = $vnet.subnets | Out-GridView -PassThru
New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -param $subnet.id xxx
```